# Number of ways to colour a square with n colours

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

A smaller square is centered inside of a larger one. If we
paint the edges of the outer square and the corners of the inner square, then
how many distinct ways are there to colour the squares, assuming we have n
colours at our disposal?

Attempt of solution:

Total number of ways to colour the squares = n^4

this is a thought by the intuition that we have n colours and 4 sides to colour
I am not sure how to give an explicit solution to this

Thanks for any help granted

Answer (score 0):

The way the problem is formulated, you have 4 edges of the outer square and 4 vertices of the inner square, a grand total of 8 object to color.

Since there seem to be no coloring restrictions, you have any of the $n$ colors to choose for any of the 8 objects, giving you a total of
$$
n \times n \times \ldots \text{8 total times} \ldots \times n = n^8
$$
choices.